# Enriching DataStream with data in parquet files

Tags: java, hdfs, apache-flink, parquet, flink-streaming

I have a Kafka DataStream source which contains IDs. I also have a database which contains additional data such as Name, Mode which I want to add to the incoming data source.

My initial attempt included using Asynchronous I/O to query Hive for this data. I even window the incoming data to reduce the number of queries sent to the database. Unfortunately the source datastream is pretty big so I can't query it directly using hive as it's causing a lot of performance issues.

Now I'm thinking of using the data stored in hdfs as parquet files as a `StreamTableSource` which I can then use to enrich the incoming data from `Kafka`. So I have a couple of questions regarding this.

1. Is this a good way to go about this problem? i.e by using the data as a table source instead of async io?
2. If it is, should I be creating a table based on the windowed data and processing each window or is there a better way?

Comment: have you found a solution to this ? please share

Comment: I was able to do it using the StreamTableSource however it wasn't exactly what I wanted. Converting the table to a datastream means that it's a bounded stream which isn't really helpful in this scenario, plus it was slower. Secondly, after optimizing Hive and using ORC, the performance is much better